# JavaScript logging done before loop is finished

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to log some data coming from a CSV file using a for loop for each line. When the for loop is done, I want it to log "done", but it seems like it logs the "done" before the last line of det csv file...
CSV File:

```
CHANNEL,TITLE,TEXT
EzaguesTesting,TITLE TIL SR 1,TEKST TIL SR 1
EzaguesTesting2,TITLE TIL SR 2,TEKST TIL SR 2
EzaguesTesting3,TITLE TIL SR 3,TEKST TIL SR 3
EzaguesTesting4,TITLE TIL SR 4,TEKST TIL SR 4
EzaguesTesting5,TITLE TIL SR 5,TEKST TIL SR 5
```

The code that *should* log it:

```
fs.readdir(dirPath, async function (err, lines) {
    for await (const line of lines) {
        await new Promise(resolve => {
            fs.createReadStream(dirPath + line)
                .pipe(csv())
                .on('data', data => {
                    console.log('SR: ' + data.CHANNEL + ' Titel: ' + data.TITLE + ' Tekst: ' + data.TEXT);
                    resolve(true);
                });
        })
    }
    console.log('done');
})
```

Everything seems to work fine, other than the fact that it logs "done" one line too early...

[image]

Comment: Is it normal that you are resolving your Promise on 'data' ? It means, you are resolving it as soon as any data arrives, not at the end of the stream. I believe you should resolve `.on('end')`

Comment: Also, instead of the callback version, you could use the Promise version of `fs` : `const lines = await fs.promises.readdir(...);`

Comment: I don't think you need an `for await...of` loop here, since `lines` is a simple array and not an async iterable. A simple `for..of` should work. (I don't know if that makes any difference in regards to the problem you are having here.)

Comment: To answer the .on('end').
That wouldn't give me the data I am going to use for the actual purpose of the project. I do want to output the data from it :)

Comment: Right, but `.on('data')` only gives you a chunk, not the whole data. It's a stream, not a file. You need to concatenate all the `data` to get the full thing.

Comment: @Ivar That doesn't change anything, but I will remove the await, no need for it :)

Comment: Thank you @JeremyThille!

Used `.on('end')` to make the resolve, and now it works!

Comment: Nice, I was writing an answer, I just posted it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You resolve your Promise on 'data'. It means that, as soon as your stream sends you the first chunk, you resolve the Promise with this chunk only.

You need to send the result back `.on('end')`.

```
const files = await fs.promises.readdir(dirPath);

for (const file of files) {
    await new Promise(resolve => {

        let result 

        fs.createReadStream(dirPath + line)
            .pipe(csv())
            .on('data', data => {
                result = data;
            })
            .on('end', () => resolve(result));
    })
}
console.log('done');
```

I have made some other changes, like using the Promise version of `fs.readdir` and also renaming `lines` to `files` (you are getting file names, not lines).

Comment: That as a whole would not work, because I don't have it inside an async function. So it would error on the first line.
The actual fix you gave me, does work tho. Thank you very much for your help!